# SSHA 256 and SSHA 512 not working in CA Directory

Tags: ldap, apache-directory

LDAP server = CA DXserver r12.0 (build 6484) Linux/DXgrid 64-Bit

I am trying to edit the userPassword attribute in the users section. I am able to enter a new SSHA password and also verify it. Once entered the userPassword shows as **SSHA Hashed Password** as expected.

However while editing, if I choose a SSHA-256 / SSHA-384 or a SSHA-512 as the hash method, the userPassword attribute shows as a **SHA Hashed Password** and the password verification also fails.

I am using Apache Directory Studio eclipse plugin for testing this out.
Is there any other configuration that is required at the LDAP server level to make this work?

Thanks in Advance
Charlie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the password hashing algorithm is configured on the server side. The server will either accept a password already hashed with the appropriate algorithm, or will hash using its configured algorithm any password that it considers as not hashed. My guess is that CA server doesn't recognize the SSHA-2 hashed passwords as properly hashed. This said, I don't have experience with CA Directory specifically.

Comment: Ye . thats correct , we have raised an incident with admin team to change the hash algorithm as well